$e^{-\lVert x \rVert ^2}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\lVert x \rVert ^2} = \pi^{n/2}$
$e^{-\lVert x \rVert ^2}$ is lebesgue integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\lVert x \rVert ^2} = \pi^{n/2}$. I'm a bit lost on this, I've tried to use a particular result about the so called radial functions that says that $\int_{A^n(a,b)}g(\lVert x \rVert) dx = \int_a^bg(t)t^{n-1}dt$ where $g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $A^n(a,b) = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: a \leq \lVert x \rVert \leq b\}$. However I am failing to integrate the function $e^{-t^2}t^{n-1}$ and in the case where $n = 2$ i get that the integral $\int_a^bte^{-t^2}dt$ is far from the desired result (when taking limits over a and b), so I don't know how to solve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Use $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\lVert x \rVert^2}~\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^\infty \int_{\partial B_r(0)} e^{-\lVert x \rVert^2} ~\mathrm{d}S(x)~\mathrm{d}r$

Can you elaborate a bit more?

Yes, let me just look up a source :D

Nevermind, Roland F's answer is easier. The result I wrote down, is important though....

$$\int\dots \int  e^{-\sum_i x_i^2} \prod_k \ dx_k =\int \prod _i \ e^{-x_i^2} dx_i = \prod _i\int e^{-x_i^2} dx_i.$$
The integral may be splitted into a power of the square
$$\left(\int e^{-x^2-y^2} dx dy \right)^{\frac{n}{2}},$$ that is trivial in  polar coordinates.

Thanks! Is there any easy way of doing it with the radial formula I gave or does it complicate things unnecessarily?

Complicated things are usually unbelievably simple!

One way to evaluate $\int_a^bte^{-t^2}dt$ is by converting integration to differentiation via $\int_a^bte^{-t^2}dt=-\frac12\partial_\mu\int_a^be^{-\mu t^2}dt$ and then let $\mu=1$.

Or substitution $u = t^2$?

Okay thanks!!!!!

@H4z2: The other way is using n-d spherical coordinates, knowing that the volume element reduces to $$ d^n x = \frac{2\pi}{n}\  \prod \sin^k(\theta_k) d\theta_k \ d(r^n)$$ by induction: the $n$-sphere is a parellel bundle of $(n-1)$-spheres along a half circle as the 3-sphere is a bundle of circles. Again using $r^2$ as a variable yields  $$\int _0^{\infty }e^{-\xi }\xi ^{\frac{n}{2}-1}d\xi =\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})$$
